# Mutual SSL authentication on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an application where the client uses mutual SSL authentication through NGINX. So far, so good.

However, I want to move my project to Google App Engine and I need to use the same approach to valid the client, or at least, forward the client certificate to be validate in the application.

Is there some way to use mutual authentication on App Engine or other Google Cloud service?

Regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not be possible in GAE flexible environment because the SSL connections don't reach all the way to the actual application code. From [Request limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled#request_limits):

> - SSL connections are terminated at the load balancer. Traffic from the load balancer is sent to the instance over an encrypted channel,
>     and then forwarded to the application server over HTTP. The
>     X-Forwarded-Proto header lets you understand if the origin request was
>     HTTP or HTTPs.

I didn't find such mention about the standard env GAE, so I'm unusure if the same applies there or not.

Comment: Thanks for the report. I spent some days trying to manipulate such stuff. I'll investigate if there is this option on GCE or GKE, and will update after to have more info about that.

Comment: @maricn I just pushed the certificate by HTTP Auth, over HTTPS. I didn't find the mutual auth feature.